# how to upload a picture through dropbox with python

Tags: python

I have tried multiple ways to upload pictures in Python with the Dropbox API and it's very complicated.

```
bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def upload(ctx, *, message):
   await bot.say("Downloading the file from the link, hang on...")
   url = str(message)
   wget.download(url)
   await bot.say("Done. Now uploading it to Dropbox...")
   o = os.path.basename(url)
   with open(o, "rb") as imageFile:
        f = imageFile.read()
        b = bytearray(f)
dbx.files_upload(b, '/' + o)
```

Since the files_upload requires bytes, path I have no clue how to go about it.
I always get this error

```
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'bytearray'>
```

is there something i dont get?

Comment: Byte arrays and bytes are not equivalent. Pass in f rather than `b` since your opening in `"rb"` and you've read what's in the file to `f` it will be the contents in binary.

Answer (score 0):

just use

`dbx.files_upload(imageFile.read(), '/' + o)`